# How do I call a controller function from another controller in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 controllers in laravel  5.2

1) Apiauth controller

```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   use App\Http\Requests;
   use App\Api_auth;

   class Apiauth extends Controller
   {
       public function checkauth($reqauthkey)
       {
             $authkey=Api_auth::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();


             if($authkey->authkey!=$reqauthkey)
            return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'Authentication Failed','code'=>403],403);  
        }

 }
```

2) MobileregistrationController

```
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;


        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use App\Http\Controllers\Apiauth;
        use App\Http\Requests;
        use App\Mobile_registration;
        use App\Api_auth;

        use App\Http\Requests\CreateMobileRegistrationRequest;

        class MobileregistrationController extends Controller
        {

            public function index(Request $request)
            {

                App\Http\Controllers\Apiauth->checkauth($request->authkey);

                // $authkey=Api_auth::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();


                // if($authkey->authkey!=$request->authkey)
                //     return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'Authentication Failed','code'=>403],403);    

                $mobileregistration=Mobile_registration::all();


                if($mobileregistration->isEmpty())
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'No data found','code'=>404],404);
                else
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'true','data'=>$mobileregistration],200);
            }


            public function show($id,Request $request)
            {

                $authkey=Api_auth::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();


                if($authkey->authkey!=$request->authkey)
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'Authentication Failed','code'=>403],403);     

                $mobileregistration=Mobile_registration::find($id);

                if(!$mobileregistration)
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'No data found','code'=>404],404);
                else
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'true','data'=>$mobileregistration],200);

            }

            public function store(CreateMobileRegistrationRequest $request)
            {
                $values =$request->only(['mobile_imei','mobile_number','application_type','version','isverified','reg_date_time','authkey']);

                $authkey=Api_auth::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();


                if($authkey->authkey!=$request->authkey)
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'Authentication Failed','code'=>403],403);   

                Mobile_registration::create($values);

                return response()->json(['response'=>'true','message'=>'Values Inserted','code'=>201],201);
            }

            public function update($id,CreateMobileRegistrationRequest $request)
            {
                $mobileregistration=Mobile_registration::find($id);

                if(!$mobileregistration)
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'No matching data found for editing','code'=>404],404);

                $authkey=Api_auth::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();


                if($authkey->authkey!=$request->authkey)
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'Authentication Failed','code'=>403],403); 

                $mobileregistration->mobile_imei=$request->get('mobile_imei');
                $mobileregistration->mobile_number=$request->get('mobile_number');
                $mobileregistration->application_type=$request->get('application_type');
                $mobileregistration->version=$request->get('version');
                $mobileregistration->isverified=$request->get('isverified');
                $mobileregistration->reg_date_time=$request->get('reg_date_time');

                $mobileregistration->save();

                return response()->json(['response'=>'true','message'=>'Mobile Registration details updated successfully','code'=>200],200);


            }

            public function destroy($id,Request $request)
            {
                $mobileregistration=Mobile_registration::find($id);

                if(!$mobileregistration)
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'No matching data found for deleting','code'=>404],404);

                $authkey=Api_auth::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();


                if($authkey->authkey!=$request->authkey)
                    return response()->json(['response'=>'false','message'=>'Authentication Failed','code'=>403],403); 

                $mobileregistration->delete();

                return response()->json(['response'=>'true','message'=>'Provided details are deleted sucessfully','code'=>200],200);
            }
        }
```

Now in MobileregistrationController, for every function I want to call this function

```
     public function checkauth($reqauthkey){}
```

of Apiauth controller

But when I used this code to call this function I am gettig error message

```
    App\Http\Controllers\Apiauth->checkauth($request->authkey);
```

Error message

```
    FatalErrorException in MobileregistrationController.php line 20:
    Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Apiauth' not found
```

I have searched lot on Stackoverflow for the answers but none of solution worked for me correctly. Someone help me to rectify this.

Comment: You should change use App\Http\Controllers\Apiauth; as use Apiauth;

Comment: no, making that generated another error  ,   FatalErrorException in MobileregistrationController.php line 20:
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: `$controller = new Apiauth;` and `$controller->checkauth($request->authkey);`

Comment: hello it's not working , I used 'namespace App\Http\Controllers;' and 'use Apiauth;' , and in code i used '$controller = new Apiauth; 
        $controller->checkauth($request->authkey);'    but I am getting error message that Apiauth not found

Comment: And if I use this use App\Http\Controllers\Apiauth  then I don't get error message but it's not calling    checkauth($request->authkey) method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have route

```
Route::get('/test/index', 'TestController@index');
```

Apiauth with function test()

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class Apiauth extends Controller {

  public function test() {
   return "abc";
  }
}
```

and i have another controller TestController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Apiauth;

class TestController extends Controller {
  public function index() {
    $controller = new Apiauth;
    return $controller->test();
  }
}
```

call url `/test/index` it print `abc` . You should try my anwser and solove your problem